# Appending ampersand to a class method

Tags: c++, methods, ampersand

I came across some C++ code which looks roughly like this:

```
        void (classA::*methodA)() const noexcept
        {
            &classA::methodB
        };
```

**Note:** obviously I'm abstracting out the class name and method names in this example.

What is the purpose of `methodA`?

**Analysis of the code**

1. It appears to be referencing `methodB`, but without parentheses, so it doesn't appear to be calling the method
2. It uses ampersand `&` which reads to me as `take the address of`
3. Lastly `methodA` doesn't return anything

Overall it appears to be just referencing the `address of` methodB.

Any suggestions as to what this is accomplishing?

Comment: This won't compile, so what it does is a moot point.

Comment: Hmm, it does compile for me.  Unless its hiding behind some #ifdef that I don't see.  Also I do see it being called.  I can try adding a printf to see if its really being called.

Comment: You've shown 3 lines of code. Please make a [mre]

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?  To me this should not compile as `classA::*methodA` is not the proper syntax for a member pointer or a member function pointer.

Comment: Ok, sorry.  I'll get a minimal reproducible example..

Comment: so i found it difficult to get a MRE since I'm not really clear how this works.  but @metal provided a great example and explanation.  I'll review all answer and accept one of these, since they answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

The key information is that you're initializing a pointer to a member function (PMF) using brace initializer syntax. See the [C++ FAQs on PMFs](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Here's your code illustrated and commented, with an alternate way to write the same thing that is less confusing because it uses a type alias:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Declare a class with a non-static method
class classA 
{
public:
    void methodB() const noexcept { std::cout << "methodB\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    // Declare a function pointer by the name of methodA 
    // and initialize it to point to classA::methodB
    void (classA::*methodA)() const noexcept
    {
        &classA::methodB
    };

    // Create an instance of classA
    const auto a = classA{};

    // Call a method on our instance using the function pointer
    (a.*methodA)();
   
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // A clearer equivalent of the above:

    // Declare an alias for the function pointer type
    using FnPtr = void (classA::*)() const noexcept;

    // Create an instance of the function pointer type,
    // also using brace initialization and pointing to `classA::methodB`
    const auto method = FnPtr{ &classA::methodB };

    // Call the function indirectly through the function pointer
    (a.*method)();    
}
```

See it live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76ecf8061eb4a670)</kbd>, where it prints:

```
methodB
methodB
```

One even shorter method if you don't need to know the type (e.g., it's just a local variable, not a member of a class) is that you can use `auto` to infer the type:

```cpp
const auto someMethod = &classA::methodB;
(a.*someMethod)();
```

If you still don't want to type that alias out but need the type in a context where you can't use `auto`, you could use `decltype` to declare it:

```cpp
// Alias using decltype
using FnPtr = decltype( &classA::methodB );

// Declare instance using decltype (e.g., as a class member)
decltype( &classA::methodB ) method = nullptr;
// ... 
// set it later:
method = &classA::methodB;

// Define template param using decltype
auto fnPtrs = std::vector< decltype( &classA::methodB ) >{};
```

Comment: oh wow, nice answer.  let me review it closer, but i think it answers my question.

Comment: Added a couple of footnotes about using `auto` and `decltype` instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Any suggestions as to what this is accomplishing?

It is defining a variable named `methodA` and initializing it to `&classA::methodB`.

The type of the variable is

a pointer to a `const` member function of `classA` that takes no arguments, returns `void`, and the member function does not throw any exceptions.

The variable is initialized to `&classA::methodB`.

If you make it a one-liner, it would be:

```
void (classA::*methodA)() const noexcept {&classA::methodB};
```

which is equivalent to:

```
void (classA::*methodA)() const noexcept = &classA::methodB;
```

Comment: thx!  i think this also answers my question.  let me review the other answers and decide which one to accept.